# Arithmetic operators undefined for 'logical' and 'Period' classes

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

```
DT1 <- data.table(Date = NA, Diff = 5)

DT1[!is.na(Date), val := Date + lubridate::days(Diff)]

Error in Date + lubridate::days(Diff) : 
  Arithmetic operators undefined for 'logical' and 'Period' classes:
  convert one to numeric or a matching time-span class.
```

What should I do so that if column Date is NA, then val is NA? Currently the lubridate is giving errors.

Comment: If the columns have only NA element, then have a check and don't add 'Date' i.e. `i1 <- DT1[, all(is.na(Date))]; if(!i1) DT1[!is.na(Date), val := Date + lubridate::days(Diff)]`

Comment: as.Date(NA)? Obviously adding anything to NA will also result in NA.